# Cakephp paging with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I am using cakephp framework with .htaccess. One of my page URL was: domainname.com/users/testing and I have changed that to domainname.com/users/user-name

My **problem** is that page contain cakephp pagination and when I put mouse pointer on the links it is showing me `domainname.com/users/testing?page:2` instead I want to show `domainname.com/users/user-name/page/2`

Can anyone help me what to change in which file.

Thanks in advance.!!!

Comment: have you changed the url by renaming you action in CakePHP or by an .htacess rule?

Answer (score 1):

You can use routes ([LINK](http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration)). It is very easy to change the url to your needs without working in the .htaccess file.You find the file routes.php in the app/config directory.

Mark Story wrote an article about custom route classes ([LINK](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-custom-route-classes-in-cakephp))